# Visual Studio 2015 C++ Cross Platform Remote Configuration error

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio, configuration, cross-platform

I'm trying to configurate my Visual Studio to build my cordova Application for iOS.
I used the microsoft instruction found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147405.aspx

At the moment im at "Configure the remote agent in Visual Studio" point 7. But at this point I'm not able to put in the information, because after selecting the point "iOS" the configuration-window is showing an error. I'm using the german version so I don't have the correct english translation but it shows something like:
"Error while loading setting page".

Any solution for this problem?
I already tried to reinstall Visual C++ iOS Cross Plattform tools, but still the same error.

Picture:
[Error Visual Studio C++ Cross-Platform iOS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH4se.png)

Comment: Does the **Pairing** tab show the same error? That's where you actually connect to `vcremote` on the Mac. If it does, you may have a corrupt install.